# Select a column from table B based on table A selected column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do the below.

```
Table A
Name ID

Table B
ID Remark
```

Select Table B Remark based on Table A Name.

Use Name to get ID in table A then match ID in table B to get Remark from Table B.

Is this possible please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [where exists](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

```
select remark from tableB b where exists (select 1 from tableA a where a.name= [give_name] and a.id=b.id);
```

or [in](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

```
select remark from tableB b where b.id in (select id from tableA where name = [give_name]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JOIN

```
SELECT remark FROM tableB b
JOIN tableA a ON a.ID = b.ID 
WHERE a.name = ?
```